# C# is slow in downloading website using StreamReader

Tags: c#

I have a desktop app for downloading the content of website.

Originally this is written in Python with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getSoup(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print "wrong"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

Then I change to using C#, the code is as follows:

```
public string getHtml(string theUrl) {
    try {
        string result = null;
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(theUrl);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Proxy = null;
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8) {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

But the C# code is much slower than the Python code. Often, C# code just doesn't have any response. Can you suggest ways to improve the C# code to make it faster?

Thank you.

Comment: This just doesn't have anything to do with C#, these transfers are handled at a much lower level.  The big difference between C# and Python is that you make an exe file appear from nowhere and immediately start doing networky things.  Disable your anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for response. I don't have any anti-malware products installed.

Answer (score 2):

1) You could use Wireshark to verify if you actually have tcp communication.
2) You should verify if it catches an exception. 
3) Use HttpWebRequest rather than WebRequest

Whatvworks for me is:

```
        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamOut.Write(yourMessage);
            }
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(streamIn.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already caught exception that may occur. But the problem is sometime the code is fast but sometime it is slow. But my Python code always gets me a response. That's what I don't know why.

Comment: You can get slight performance boost by adding compression header like `request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate`

Answer (score 0):

Try Restsharp

```
public string GetHtml(string theUrl)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(theUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "c9d3ea79-0e8e-b377-a6c7-0042b1f82d51");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "tokenDate=10%2F08%2F2017&enrollId=446", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
```